# Where put jQuery UI Bootstrap in Rails

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I'm using Bootstrap and jQuery UI in my app and to get those two work side by side I need to integrate [jQuery UI Bootstrap](http://jquery-ui-bootstrap.github.io/jquery-ui-bootstrap/index.html). I think all of those gems around which integrates assets pipeline are out of date so I've decided to download this CSS files and put the manually inside my project but I'm stuck on instructions:

1. Download the archive
2. Unzip archive
3. Locate the folder `custom-theme`
   inside the css folder inside the newly uncompressed file
4. Move that
   folder inside the css directory of the website for which you want to
   use jquery-ui-bootstrap
5. Include the appropriate .css files in the
   layout of your website

First of all, third point on list... CSS directory, so I guess `app/assets/stylesheets`? But, inside this library I have `images` directory, where to put it? And also is `app/assets` a good place for third party libraries? Maybe `vendors` or `lib` at least?
What is more, **Include the appropriate .css files in the layout...** How!? when I go to `application.css.scss` and write e. g. `*= require jquery-ui-1.10.3.theme` will the asset pipeline know that this file is in `vendor` or `lib`?

I've tried the approach of putting css files to `app/assets/stylesheets` and images to `app/assets/images` so the application.js by default imports this directory but I didn't get images on website...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every third party library should be added to the `vendor/assets` folder. In there you see if the files belong under js or css folder.

Now when this is done you go to the `application.css` or `application.js` in `app/assets javascripts` or `stylesheets` and require the library that you want to use.

For instance for my `angular-growl-notifications.min` that is in `vendor/assets/javascripts` I say `#= require angular-growl-notifications.min` in `application.js`